# Is there any way to set a Terraform ressource attribute using its name?

Tags: terraform

Is there any way to set a Terraform resource attribute using its name?

I would like to use a map variable containing a map/object and would like to dynamically set attribute on a resource based on that object using a loop.

Basically be able to do something similar to helm_release set mechanism (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release):

```
resource "helm_release" "example" {
  name       = "my-redis-release"
  ...
  set {
    name  = "cluster.enabled"
    value = "true"
  }
```

Ideally I would like to do something like taking a .yaml and load into a variable as a map/object, then use that variable in a module in a loop to set resources attributes :

```
var.attributes = { a = 4, d = 2 }

resource "type" "name" {
   for_each = var.attributes
   .. 
   self[each.key]    = each.value
}
```

I am using terraform 0.14.

Comment: I'm not sure from your question what your intended result is. Could you edit your question to show a configuration written out "longhand" (without the mechanism you're asking about) and then describe what you'd like to improve about that longer configuration?

Comment: @MartinAtkins I added some example.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in Terraform to generate the arguments of a resource block entirely dynamically from data elsewhere.

The Terraform language expressions allow you to dynamically set the values of particular arguments, but the arguments themselves must always be set statically because a resource object in Terraform is more like a struct or class in a general-purpose language, rather than a dictionary or map where you can freely set whichever keys you like.

The closest you can get to what you included in your question is a resource with the arguments listed out explicitly but with their values assigned from the variable, like this:

```
resource "type" "name" {
  a = var.attributes.a
  b = var.attributes.b
}
```

Terraform will then statically validate that all of the arguments you've specified are valid arguments of the resource type and that the expressions you assigned to each of them conform to the expected type constraints.